# Accessing BindingList from another class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access my BindingList from another class but I'm unsure how to do it.

Here is my code from my Form2 class:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //List containing the memos added
    public static BindingList<memo> memosList = new BindingList<memo>();
    //Now the list needs to be initialized so i can use it elsewhere
    public static BindingList<memo> Memos
    {
        get { return memosList; }
        set { memosList = value; }
    }

    //...
```

and here is the code from my Form3 class:

```
private void CreateMemo(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    memo memosList = new memo();
    memosList.Add(
        new memo(priorityNumber.Text, memoTitle.Text, memoDescription.Text));
}
```

How would I access the list in Form2 so that I can add/remove items from it?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BindingList<memo>` is declared as a static property so you can access it by using `Form2.Memos` to add or remove items in die `Form3` class.

```
private void CreateMemo(object sender, EventArgs args)
{            
     Form2.Memos.Add(
            new memo(priorityNumber.Text, memoTitle.Text, memoDescription.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've made your memolist public static, it makes no sense to have a property for it.  Martijn van Put provides a good answer, but I wouldn't understand why having two variable names that point to the same memory location.

This also does the same thing that Martijn van Put

```
private void CreateMemo(object sender, EventArgs args)
{            
     Form2.memoslist.Add(
            new memo(priorityNumber.Text, memoTitle.Text, memoDescription.Text));
}
```

Here's a reference to using properties... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx